# New to Cygwin, help please

Tags: cygwin

I'm a little new to cygwin and I want to edit my .emacs file. During the install, I added the emacs package but I don't know where the .emacs file is located. Any ideas?

Also, when I'm trying to run a certain executable, I get the following error:

```
unhandled exception: Fail: unknown system type, CYGWIN_NT-6.1-WOW64
```

Is there some 64bit vs. 32 bit problem I'm experiencing? I don't really understand what it's saying. Am I missing a package? Thank you.

Comment: Please separate (edit) this question into two separate questions, you'll stand a better chance of getting an answer, since you'll be able to have a meaningful title.

Comment: And please provide more information about this "certain executable".

Answer (score 1):

I can answer on your first question :

if you installed cygwin on your C: then it would be c:\cygwin\home\yourusername\.emacs. However this file might not be auto generated and you might have to create it manually.